# Android Studio login system database problem

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, login-system

I am trying to make a simple login registration system and I watch a video from youtube and this problem come up.

```
        public Boolean chkmail(String email) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where email=?", new String[]{email});
            if(cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
            else return true;
```

this is the line where thing goes wrong

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from user where email=?", new String[]{email});
```

[image: g]

my app went crashed  when i register an account.
im using sqlite.

this is the database helper code

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table user(email text primary key, password text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists user");
    }
    public boolean insert(String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("email", email);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long ins = db.insert("user", null, contentValues);
        if(ins==-1) return false;
        else return true;
```

Comment: can you pass the error please ?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: email (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: Select * from user where email=?

Comment: post the code where you are creating the table.

Comment: @KaranMer i showed the database helper code

Answer (score 0):

> no such column: email

This means your column doesn't exist in your table. If you have added it later , please uninstall the app , or increment the database schema .